# Replacing while for indexOf

Tags: javascript

I wrote this relatively simple code to find the point in a sorted array where a value should be inserted.

```
function findInsertionIndex(array, value){
    var i = 0
    while(array[i]){
        if(value<array[i].value) break
        i++
    }
    return i
}
```

This code works great, but I wanted to replace it with indexOf on an array for readability and brevity. I tried this where value is in the outer scope:

```
var insertionIndex = array.findIndex(e=> e.value<value) || 0
```

Can anybody point out what is missing?

## Runnable

```js
function findInsertionIndex(array, value){
  var i = 0
  while(array[i]){
    if(value<array[i].value) break
    i++
  }
  return i
}

// Run the code
a = [{value:1},
     {value:5},
     {value:6},
     {value:7},
     {value:9},
     {value:23},
     {value:84}]
ind = findInsertionIndex(a, 15)
console.log(ind)

////////
// Try with indexOf
////////
a = []
value = 15

// Add a first item
ind = a.findIndex(e=> e.value<value)
ind = ind>0 ? ind : 0
a.splice(ind, 0, 3)

// Add a second item
ind = a.findIndex(e=> e.value<value)
ind = ind>0 ? ind : 0
a.splice(ind, 0, 5)

// Add a third item
ind = a.findIndex(e=> e.value<value)
ind = ind>0 ? ind : 0
a.splice(ind, 0, 4)



console.log(a)
```

Comment: What error are you getting in your developer tools console?

Comment: There is no error, it simply produces the wrong output.

Comment: I think you meant `e => e.value<value`

Comment: really, no error? That's not valid javascript you posted. Also, no code uses `indexOf`, so .. not sure why you've indicated you want to use it, then have not

Comment: `I think you meant` - no, because `There is no error` ... so that must be right ... :p

Comment: Oh sorry yes I did accidentally change that before copying `e=>e.value<value` is correct

Comment: Can you please make it runnable or put a demo up so it can be debugged properly

Comment: The fastest way to find the insertion point for a sorted array is to use a binary search. There is probably some code out there for you to copy/paste.

Comment: You need to provide the structure of the elements of the array.  `e => e < value` works correctly for integers.  This works: `var a = [10, 5]; var idx = a.findIndex( e => e < 6 ) || 0;`

Comment: Hopefully this clears it up. Sorry about the confusion guys. I should have been clearer with my original question.

Comment: Yes, it clears it up.  It's a logic error.  The first element of the array is smaller than your test value so it's returning 0.  You need to get rid of the `|| 0` if you're going to use an ascending sort since 0 is a valid value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what does the `findIndex` method exactly?

> The findIndex() method returns an index in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is returned.

And since you check if the array value is smaller than the tested value (`e.value < value`), it's always the first index (i.e. `0`) what it returns.

To get what you want, you have to reverse the logic like this: `e.value > value`, then it's equivalent with your while loop.

Your index assignment (`ind`) needs also to be changed, because the meaning of no found is now that there is no smaller element in the array (i.e. the value is the greatest one):

`ind = ind >= 0 ? ind : a.length`

Maybe take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cLqf6vg8/

I don't know if it's an important question to you, but you can also think about what happens if the values are equal. Should it be inserted before or after. If you want it before use `>=`, otherwise `>`.

But as some commentators said, if your array is **sorted**, there are some better and faster algorithms out there like the **binary search** (also easy to implement).

Comment: I've edited the runnable to clarify how this is meant to be used. This change doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Okay, the problem is that you also need to reverse the logic of the ``ind`` assignment, I will add this point to the answer.

Comment: I'm aware of the possibility of a binary search. I just want something that is easy to read as opposed to fast, as I won't usually have too many items in this array.

Comment: Did you check out the working example in the fiddle? I think it is totally working - as you want. Maybe just change ``e`` to ``e.value`` if you want to implement it with objects instead of integers.

Comment: Yes your fiddle is works a treat :) Thanks for that! It turns out the error I had was just syntax. The change from `:` to `=>` seemed to fix it. I ended up creating a `SortedArray` class that uses a binary search anyway, because theres no good reason not to binary search when you have a sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because the `<` needs reversed?

```
value<array[i].value
```

vs

```
e.value<value
```